# Custom primaryKey Laravel + Apiato

Tags: php, laravel

I created table with custom primary key. It is uuid "message_id".

But when trying to insert data into it, I am getting following message _

> "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' ..."_ .

Tried with

```
protected $primaryKey = 'message_id';
public $incrementing = false;
```

but no luck.

My model looks like:

```
protected $table = 'messages';

protected $primaryKey = 'message_id';
public $incrementing = false;

protected $fillable = [
    'message_id',
    'sender_id',
    'recipient_id',
    'message_text',
    'time',
];
```

Query:

```
$newMessage = $this->messageRepository->create([
    'sender_id'    => $sender_id,
    'recipient_id' => $recipient_id,
    'message_text' => $message_text,
]);

$newMessage->save();
```

Comment: show table description. REAL table description.

Comment: Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('message_id');
            $table->uuid('sender_id');
            $table->uuid('recipient_id');
            $table->string('message_text');
            $table->boolean('seen');

            $table->primary('message_id');

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

Comment: No, open a mysql shell, run `DESCRIBE yourtable;` and post the output. Your code looks good; I have a feeling your table is out of sync with migration.

Comment: `create table messages
(
 message_id char(36) not null
  primary key,
 sender_id char(36) not null,
 recipient_id char(36) not null,
 message_text varchar(191) not null,
 seen tinyint(1) not null,
 created_at timestamp null,
 updated_at timestamp null,
 deleted_at timestamp null
)
;`

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem. In model I had `Use Uuids;`

trait Uuids had predefined " `'default_uuid_column' => 'id'` "